# PostgreSQL's JSON type returns null

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I have the following record in `technologies` column:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"PHP"},{"id":2,"name":"Laravel"}]
```

When I run query like:

```
SELECT  technologies->>'name' AS name FROM technologies;
```

It always returns null, though record is right there.

I am using Postgres 9.3

Comment: You have an array of elements there, so you need to first get the desired array element: `(technologies -> 1)->>'name'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of json elements there, so you need to first get the desired array element: `(technologies -> 0)->>'name'` or `(technologies -> 1)->>'name'`

You can also use the function `json_array_elements` to convert the elements to rows:

```
select json_array_elements(technologies)->>'name'
from technologies;
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. But what if structure present as `['item1','item2']`. How do I receive then since there is no key here.

Comment: @Volatil3 If you have a different JSON document than shown, then why did you show the one in your question? That's again an array where you need to extract each element using the `->` operator or split it to rows using the `json_array_elements` function. The real question actually is: why do you store this information as JSON in the first place? Just because JSON is currently hyped and Postgres supports it really good, doesn't mean you need to throw everything about proper relational design away

Comment: Pardon, actually I had a couple of structure and I should have put both in it. To answer your questions. The types are `json` as structure would change in future and it's not good to create a separate table and join for something which would change.